# Is it possible to declare extern "C" functions without polluting the namespace?

Tags: namespaces, rust, ffi

In Rust, `extern C` functions can be declared in the outer scope:

```
#[link(name = "some_lib")]
extern "C" {
    pub fn foo(path: *const c_char);
    pub fn bar(path: *const c_char);
    pub fn baz(path: *const c_char);
    pub fn fez(path: *const c_char);
}
```

While acceptable, each function needs to be accessed directly `foo()` `bar()`... etc.

Is it possible to declare these in a way they can be accessed using a common prefix?

Example of how encapsulation could work:

```
namespace some_lib {
    #[link(name = "some_lib")]
    extern "C" {
        pub fn foo(path: *const c_char);
        // ... etc ...
    }
}

fn some_rust_function() {
    unsafe {
        some_lib::foo();  // <-- example usage
    }

}
```

Is something like this possible?

Comment: This seems like an obvious "right thing" for the language to offer, but I'm not sure if it does or not. If you find that this is not supported, you should request it on the Rust forums. In the mean time, couldn't you simply wrap every extern-C function in a Rust function and expose the wrapper functions instead of the underlying C functions?

Comment: Ah, thanks, I might do this, though it has the tradeoff that `#[link(name = "some_lib")]` will be copy-pasted all over, any arguments, eg - to make static, will need to be copy-pasted too.

Comment: I'm confused; why can't you just put them in a module?

Comment: @DK, at that works (am new and didn't use module yet), did you want to post answer? Else I will.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just use a module.

```rust
mod ffi {
    extern "C" {
        pub fn exit(_: i32) -> !;
    }
}

fn main() {
    unsafe { ffi::exit(1); }
}
```